# which function for factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe, operators

I would like to use `which` function with `arr.ind = TRUE` for a `data.frame`. It produces the correct result if I use it columnwise. But I could not get this for the whole `data.frame`.

Note: I edited the code. Also, the expected output is added to the code.

MWE:

```
df <- data.frame(f1 = factor(c("a","b","a","x","x")), 
                 f2 = factor(c("a","x","x","x","b")))

which(df %in% c("a","b"), arr.ind = TRUE)
# integer(0)  # This is not what I expect

# Expected output
# row col
#   1   1
#   2   1
#   3   1
#   1   2
#   5   2
```

Comment: `df %in% c("a","x")` will return FALSE

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. I have edited the code.

Comment: One workaround to this is `which(df=="a" | df=="x")`

Comment: Summarizing comments from deleted answer: (a) Please show your expected output and (b) If your goal is not that output (you mentioned replacing values), please ask about your real goal.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks for your valuable comments, I attached expected output.

Comment: @nsinghs, I noticed that your reply is enough to solve my problem. I just need to add the argument `arr.ind = T`. Thanks.

Comment: @mert yes that should do it

Comment: But if one needs a simple function for comparison in case more inputs like`df=="a" | df=="b" | df=="c" | df=="d"`, he needs a simpler method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method:

```
x = as.matrix(df) %in% c("a", "b")
cbind(row(df)[x], col(df)[x])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    1
# [3,]    3    1
# [4,]    1    2
# [5,]    5    2
```

If you're intending to replace these values, going column-by-column over the whole data frame will probably be most efficient (not using this result).